# How to test Woocommerce webhooks in java

Tags: java, woocommerce, webhooks

I am working on ecommerce application which is having backend written in java programming langauge.

Application is having code to listen Woocommerce Webhook events. I logged in Woocommerce site and check Webhook configuration and logs in Woocomerce->Status->logs. Logs are showing 200 status code in response. So, no problem I can see in Woocommerce webhook but my application is not listening any webhook events like order.created, etc.

What I was thinking to test it with any example java source code sothat I can get where is problem.

So, if anyone is having good java source code to test Woocommerce Webhook, Please suggest. If anyone face this problem ever, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you are fully aware of what WOO-Webhooks are intended to do.

Basically is send some post data to a specific link and from there it's up to you to do whatever wanted with data.

[image: img]

A simple `receiver`with php can be (that you specified at Delivery URL)

```
<?php
//echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
$msg = "woo order \n";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
    $data  = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $msg .= strval($data);
}
    
// send email
mail("yourmail@mail.com","woo order",strval($msg));
//echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
```

Response on mail can be something like:
[image: resp]

Instead of processing, `data` is dumped  to mail. It's up to you here to implement any logic since you got the data.

If wanted to process something with another language `java` then adapt it (do a web-server, externalize the link, process as suitable the data). Same steps as example provided.

On Logs can be found addition information about what was delivered, how ...

[image: logs]